# Женское имя Даниля в дательном падеже

Tags: орфография

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать имя Даниля в дательном падеже?

Comment: А что говорят словари личных имён? Ваше мнение имеется?

Answer (score 1):

Имя  скорее  всего  татарское — Даниля́.  Значит — Даниле́.

Comment: Уважаемый  dionys,  подскажите,  как  обозначить  ударение  надстрочным  значком ?